# Angular Material 2: How to refresh md-table after editing a record?

Tags: angular-material2

So I have a user-list component and a user-detail component.

The user-list component has an md-table listing all users registered. The user is able to click on a button to see the details of the corresponding entity.

After editing the Name property and saving (for example), the user-detail redirects to the user-list component. But the md-table displays the old information.

How can I trigger an md-table refresh after editing the entity in another component like this scenario?

Here is my user-list component:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
tableDisplayedColumns: string[] = ['userName', 'email', 'options'];
userDataSource: UserDataSource;

constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userDataSource = new UserDataSource(this._userService);
}}



class UserDataSource extends DataSource<UserVModel> {
constructor(private _userService: UserService) { 
    super();
}

connect(): Observable<UserVModel[]> {
    return this._userService.getAllUsers();
}

disconnect(): void { }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table will re-render when the stream provided by `connect()` emits a new value.

`getAllUsers` needs to emit a new set of data when it is changed. Otherwise, listen for a separate stream (e.g. `dataChanged`) from the `_userService` and use that to call `getAllUsers` again.

```
connect(): Observable<UserVModel[]> {
  return this._userService.dataChanged
      .switchMap(() => this._userService.getAllUsers()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It leaded me in the right direction to find what was going wrong with my application. I think that both answers are going to be of great value to people starting on angular and material 2.

Comment: I had to develop a Delete procedure, and then I used this approach to achieve the desired result. The only thing is that I had to include a .Delay(250) in my dataChanged observable before .switchMap. Otherwise it would trigger the getAllUsers service before the Entity Framework finish updating it's cache or something, and would end up returning the same old data. Probably not the best approach, but it's the only I found to work right.

Comment: I imagine you would want dataChanged to be based on the Entity Framework finishing its task rather than the triggering of the database change. You are asking for a race condition if you are creating an arbitrary delay

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of how can I do this? It would be veeeery appreciated.

Comment: Without having access to your app architecture and how things are stored/retrieved from the database, I don't think I'll be able to provide much help

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that the User-Detail component was redirecting before the observable had the chance to complete. So I placed the router.navigate as a complete function.

Code Before

```
onSubmit() {
    this._updateSub = this._service.updateUser(this._id, this._userForm.value)
                                        .subscribe(null, err => this.onSubmitError(err));
    this._router.navigate(['/user']);
}
```

Code After

```
onSubmit() {
    this._updateSub = this._service.updateUser(this._id, this._userForm.value)
                                        .subscribe(null, err => this.onSubmitError(err), () => this.afterSubmit());
}
afterSubmit() {
    this._router.navigate(['/user']);
}
```

Prior to this change, I was getting the old values after the redirect. Using the complete function, I get up to date values without the need to use a dataChanged observable in the service.

Answer (score 0):

You could tidy things up and put your router navigation inside the response :

```
onSubmit() {
this._updateSub = this._service.updateUser(this._id, 
this._userForm.value).subscribe(
   res => this._router.navigate(['/user']);
   err => this.onSubmitError(err), () => this.afterSubmit());
}
```

Comment: If I do this, I will end up redirecting before the Entity Framework complete it's job. I tried before. The only way that works, is if I redirect on observable complete. It gives time to the database make the changes and update the caches.